# Log4j2 converting multiline logs stacktraces into single line

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j2, pattern-layout

I'm trying to push the logs my Elasticserver logs to rsys and then FLuentd. For this the stacktrace error logs should be in one line.

It was multiline before

```
443 [2022-08-05T07:45:38,068][ERROR][o.e.i.g.GeoIpDownloader  ] [techsrv01] exception during geoip databases update
   444  org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: not all primary shards of [.geoip_databases] index are active
   445      at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.updateDatabases(GeoIpDownloader.java:137) ~[ingest-geoip-7.17.5.jar:7.17.5]
   446      at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.runDownloader(GeoIpDownloader.java:284) [ingest-geoip-7.17.5.jar:7.17.5]
   447      at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:100) [ingest-geoip-7.17.5.jar:7.17.5]
   448      at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:46) [ingest-geoip-7.17.5.jar:7.17.5]
   449      at org.elasticsearch.persistent.NodePersistentTasksExecutor$1.doRun(NodePersistentTasksExecutor.java:42) [elasticsearch-7.17.5.jar:7.17.5]
   450      at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:777) [elasticsearch-7.17.5.jar:7.17.5]
   451      at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26) [elasticsearch-7.17.5.jar:7.17.5]
   452      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
   453      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
   454      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

After changing the pattern layout in log4j2.properties in the below format. I'm able to get it into two lines. But I'm not able to convert it more into single line.

> appender.rolling_old.layout.pattern =
> [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}][%node_name] %marker %m %n
> %throwable{separator(|)}

---

```
2028     [2022-08-05T11:04:40,810][ERROR][o.e.i.g.GeoIpDownloader  ][techsrv01]  exception during geoip databases update
      2029   ElasticsearchException[not all primary shards of [.geoip_databases] index are active]| at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.updateDatabases(GeoIpDownloader.java:137)|    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.runDownloader(GeoIpDownloader.java:284)|  at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:100)|  at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:46)|   at org.elasticsearch.persistent.NodePersistentTasksExecutor$1.doRun(NodePersistentTasksExecutor.java:42)|   at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:777)|  at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)| at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)|   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)|   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)[2022-08-05T11:04:41,171][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService][techsrv01]  Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.07.18-000001][0], [.kibana-event-log-7.17.5-000001][0], [.geoip_databases][0], [.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.07.18-000001][0]]]).
```

How can we achieve this using Log4j2 layout pattern?

Comment: for indexing, are you using logstash or filebeat /

Comment: was planning to push from rsys and for indexing using FluentD. But using RSYS, I was unable to achieve the results, also I couldn't convert the logs into 1 line. So, used the default logs and ditched RSYS and just using FluentD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting the logs in one single line using log4j2. I used the default log pattern. And I ditched RSYS instead used FluentD directly to parse the logs, below configuration will only filter **warn** and **error** and not **info**

td-agent.conf

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticdemo.log
  pos_file /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticdemo.log.pos
  tag elastic_error_self
  <parse>
    @type multiline
    format_firstline /(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/
    format1 /^(?<timestamp>\[.*?\])(?<logLevel>\[.*?\])(?<service>\[.*?\]) (?<node_name>\[.*?\])(?<message>.*)/
  </parse>
</source><filter **>
  @type grep
  <exclude>
    key logLevel
    pattern /INFO/
    # or, to exclude all messages that are empty or include only white-space
  </exclude>
</filter><match elastic**>
  @type elasticsearch
  host elasticIP/lbip/vmip #where elastic is installed
  port 9200
  index_name elastic_error_self
  include_timestamp true #connection configs
    reconnect_on_error true
    reload_on_failure true
    slow_flush_log_threshold 90  # buffer configs
  <buffer>
    @type file
    path /data/opt/fluentd/buffer/elastic_error_self
    chunk_limit_size 32MB
    total_limit_size 20GB
    flush_thread_count 8
    flush_mode interval
    retry_type exponential_backoff
    retry_timeout 10s
    retry_max_interval 30
    overflow_action drop_oldest_chunk
    flush_interval 5s
  </buffer>
</match>
```

[image: Elastic complete multiline logs are coming with stacktraces]